# Troubles autostarting Qt app on Yocto Raspberry Pi3

Tags: qt, yocto, autostart

I'm looking to boot my Pi as quickly as possible into a Qt application.

Following [this guide](https://jumpnowtek.com/rpi/Raspberry-Pi-Systems-with-Yocto.html)
I successfully built a Yocto Linux with the necessary Qt dependencies, and I can launch my Qt app by executing the binary from the console or SSH.

I haven't managed to get it to autostart, whatever I do.

Following [this guide:](https://retifrav.github.io/blog/2017/12/08/b2qt-startup-script/)
I made a launcher /etc/init.d/autostart which points to a bash script which executes the Qt binary and appends some text to a file just for logging purposes.

/etc/init.d/autostart is below

```
#!/bin/sh
# https://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          autostart
# Required-Start:    $all
# Required-Stop:
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Autostart
### END INIT INFO

# http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Path-4.html
#PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin

case "$1" in
  start)
    logger "Starting autostart scripts"

    # your scripts here
    /home/root/bootScript.sh

    logger $?
    exit 0
    ;;
  *)
    echo "It's just a startup script and has no arguments or commands"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
```

/home/root/bootScript.sh is below

```
#!/bin/sh
/home/root/testProject_01/testProject_01
echo "howdy" >> /home/root/some.txt
```

Ran update-rc.d autostart defaults to register it with the system.

I also have the system auto-logging in as root:
/etc/inittab has the following line added to the bottom:
    1:2345:respawn:/bin/login -f root tty1 /dev/tty1 2>&1.

full /etc/inittab is below

```
# /etc/inittab: init(8) configuration.
# $Id: inittab,v 1.91 2002/01/25 13:35:21 miquels Exp $

# The default runlevel.
id:5:initdefault:

# Boot-time system configuration/initialization script.
# This is run first except when booting in emergency (-b) mode.
si::sysinit:/etc/init.d/rcS

# What to do in single-user mode.
~~:S:wait:/sbin/sulogin

# /etc/init.d executes the S and K scripts upon change
# of runlevel.
#
# Runlevel 0 is halt.
# Runlevel 1 is single-user.
# Runlevels 2-5 are multi-user.
# Runlevel 6 is reboot.

l0:0:wait:/etc/init.d/rc 0
l1:1:wait:/etc/init.d/rc 1
l2:2:wait:/etc/init.d/rc 2
l3:3:wait:/etc/init.d/rc 3
l4:4:wait:/etc/init.d/rc 4
l5:5:wait:/etc/init.d/rc 5
l6:6:wait:/etc/init.d/rc 6
# Normally not reached, but fallthrough in case of emergency.
z6:6:respawn:/sbin/sulogin
AMA0:12345:respawn:/bin/start_getty 115200 ttyAMA0 vt102
# /sbin/getty invocations for the runlevels.
#
# The "id" field MUST be the same as the last
# characters of the device (after "tty").
#
# Format:
#  <id>:<runlevels>:<action>:<process>
#

#1:12345:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty1

1:2345:respawn:/bin/login -f root tty1 </dev/tty1 >/dev/tty1 2>&1
```

When I reboot, there is one more "howdy" in /home/root/some.txt, but Qt app does not auto start, just lands on the console.

When I manually call /etc/init.d/autostart start, it starts correctly.

Can anyone of you smart people figure out why is this happening?
Is it something to do with the order of execution - Is the Qt app not starting because root hasn't logged in yet?

- Rpi3
- Using the official 7" cap touch DPI TFT.

Greatful for any pointers.
Thanks

Comment: Your question is missing the content of the init script. And before, please take the [tour] and read [ask] to learn how you can improve your question in general.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added the script contents. Originally didn't want to add too much what I thought was irrelevance. I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: After trying a few more things I got it to autostart by executing the Qt binary from /etc/profile. Not sure if this is the best thing to do, but it sure does work!

Comment: This is a very bad idea; the profile gets executed (almost) each time a shell is started. You most probably get multiple instances already on boot.

Comment: @Murphy do you have any suggestions about how to do it better? Thanks

Comment: Only the [well-known ones](https://www.dexterindustries.com/howto/run-a-program-on-your-raspberry-pi-at-startup/).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
I found a solution that works but not sure if it is correct :)

```
vi /etc/init.d/autostart
```

than i add this code from 
[Burkhard Stubert](https://github.com/bstubert/meta-cuteradio/blob/master/recipes-apps/radio/files/cuteradio)

```
#!/bin/sh

. /etc/init.d/functions

do_start() {
    /usr/local/bin/cuteradio -platform eglfs &
}

do_stop() {
    killproc cuteradio
}

case "$1" in
  start)
    echo "Starting cuteradio app"
    do_start
    ;;
  stop)
    echo "Stopping cuteradio app"
    do_stop
    ;;
  restart|force-reload)
    echo "Restarting cuteradio app"
    do_stop
    sleep 1
    do_start
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|force-reload}" >&2
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

change the path and proc name to your app than i do

```
chmod +x /etc/init.d/autostart
update-rc.d autostart defaults 70
```

and it works for me.
hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for sharing. I will try this!

Comment: @ASMotionLab did it work?